# How do I control when my custom check-in policy is evaluated?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I've created a custom check-in policy for TFS by writing a class that extends `PolicyBase` (as per [MSDN How To: Create Custom Check-in Policies in Visual Studio Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx)). The overridden `Evaluate()` method is where I've got my logic.

`Evaluate()` gets called when the user clicks the Check In button in TFS which is great as that is what I want.

However, it also seems like `Evaluate()` gets called when:

1. Visual Studio is launched AND
2. The user navigates to the Pending Changes tab for the first time (or if this is already the active tab when VS is launched) AND
3. The user has items in the pending changes tab.

How can I check under what scenario Evaluate is called? I would only like Evaluate to be called when the user explicitly clicks the Check In button in TFS.

The actual Evaluate method I'm using is quite complicated but I've simplified it to something that still exhibits the same problem:

```
public override PolicyFailure[] Evaluate()
{
    List<PolicyFailure> policyFailures = new List<PolicyFailure>();

    if (_isPolicyEnabled)
    {
        if (PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.Comment.Contains("*"))
        {
            string msg = "Star in comment";
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            policyFailures.Add(new PolicyFailure(msg, this));
        }
    }
    return policyFailures.ToArray();
}
```

With the above code, if there is a star in the check-in comment and there are Pending Changes, close Visual Studio, when you re-open it will throw up the MessageBox as soon as you navigate to the Pending Changes tab.

The way the check-in policy is being used in my situation is that I check the user's comment for references to items in another system. If they are not present then I throw up an interactive dialog that shows the user a list of items which can be filtered and selected. These are then inserted into their check-in comment. Is there a way within the `Evaluate()` to find out under which scenario it is called? I could avoid throwing up the dialog under all calls except those triggered by a Check-In.

Comment: Can you give us some code. Because afaik Evaluate() shouldn't get called all the times you've mentioned: "The check-in framework executes this method when the user clicks the Policies button or attempts a check-in or shelving operation." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163320.aspx

Comment: @Feroc: that article is a bit vague about the evaluation mechanism.  Evaluation will always be called before a check-in or shelve, and to draw the check-in policies channel, but it may also be called at any other time to keep the internal state up-to-date.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: hmmm... I've created a policy some time ago and can't remember such a behaviour. Or maybe it just didn't matter in my example and so I just didn't notice.

Comment: Check-in policies, by definition, should not do UI interaction for exactly the reason you mention.  I suspect you're not actually just popping up a error dialog (since the policy framework provides error reporting itself).  Could you describe a little bit more about what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Feroc: in practice, it won't get called all that often (updating the policy warnings UI is the most frequent cause to need to evaluate - otherwise we try to be lazy about it because it could be expensive), but we don't make any explicit guarantees.  You may, for example, see differences in when evaluate is called between the Visual Studio and Eclipse clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Evaluate()` shouldn't display UI (as Edward Thomson already
  mentioned).
- `Evaluate()` should just create failures if there are any
  issues.

This will create a list of failures that the user can then double click on. The double clicking of a failure can then be used (handled by the `Activate()`) to trigger UI components to be displayed. I haven't tried this yet but it pretty much seems like it will work.

The details are in this MSDN forum post: [Prompting user from checkin policy occurs multiple times](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/tfsgeneral/thread/5e990d95-5514-4570-8efa-235ffbb89130).